# Will there be "upgrades" from the current physical DnD 5e PHB (and other official materials) to the One D&D versions?

Tags: dnd-5e, books, one-dnd-playtest

Do we know whether there will be an upgrade path, i.e. a set of errata that can be glued in or something like that, so existing physical PHBs into the eventual One D&D versions?

Comment: This isn't a bad question, but it's one that every person is going to have a different opinion on how to handle. Whether or not it's worth it to you will be up to you and not up to us.

Comment: Do you need them before One comes out? We can't give you a shopping recommendation, but we could answer whether or not 5e seamlessly ties into One.

Comment: I have removed the second sentence (which was kind of superfluous anyways); I'm really mostly interested in the main question, and can decide about whether to buy or not for myself, indeed. :)

Comment: The thing is, we know what they've said right now, but what they say and what they do in two years may be different things.

Answer (score 9):

### Update documents are unlikely.

Based on the previews we've seen so far, an update document as you describe it seems highly unlikely. The changes are pretty widespread and cut deep into the system, so documents detailing every change and how to apply them to the 5e books would likely be so large as to be unusable. At most I would expect instructions on how to update existing 5e characters to the One system (if necessary) and/or reassurance that the two sets of characters are totally compatible.

And from a business perspective, keep in mind that the purpose of a new edition (or whatever they want to call this) is ultimately *to sell more books*. I'm sure the writers want to make the game better and more accessible, but they wouldn't be printing anything if they didn't think they could sell it. And any document that would undercut sales -- anything that would make potential customers say, "I don't really need the new books as long as I have this document" -- well, that is not a document they're going to write.

Answer (score 5):

### There will be new rulebooks in 2024

The [announcement](https://www.dndbeyond.com/posts/1313-wizards-presents-recap-catch-up-on-all-the-d-d#one-dnd) by Wizards of the Coast stated:

> As part of One D&D, we’re…
>
> - Updating and expanding on the existing rules of the game, culminating in the release of new rulebooks in 2024;

There is no mention of glue-in errata. It's up to you to decide if you consider it worthwhile to buy a book of the current edition.

Apart for the rule books, nothing should stop you from buying any supplements or adventures in the meantime, because the announcement also states:

> The One D&D rules will be backwards compatible, allowing you to continue enjoying the adventures and supplements you play with today.

Comment: From early experience, telling people about backwards compatibility is dangerous. They have barely released anything at all and it is already far from backwards compatibility.

Comment: @SeriousBri Yes, its questionable how much is marketing here. Still, they are mostly changing rules within the existing framework. Balance my shift a bit but I would not have any issue running PCs made with the UA rules pack through Tomb of Annihilation, without making changes to the module.

Comment: @SeriousBri Depends on your definition on "Backwards compatible". Its easy to interpret this in different ways, but so far it seems they mean backwards compatible for "adventures and supplements" but not the core rulebooks, which is what they are essentially rewriting. I take that to mean you could pick up the new rules with new characters and still play your "Hoard of the Dragon Queen" adventure.

Answer (score -3):

**If you want to play 5e, buy 5e**. Role playing games are not like software, you don't have to use the latest and greatest version.

If you want to play D&D One, wait for D&D One to be released. Just be prepared that there **may not be as much supporting material** (adventures, supplements) as there currently is for 5e at the release date, although D&D One is supposed to be compatible with 5e adventures and campaigns.

I'd say if you want to start a campaign within the next year or so, and **want one of those versions of D&D**, just **go for 5e**. It works and has a good variety of material available.

Comment: "*Role playing games are not like software, you don't have to use the latest and greatest version.*" this isn't necessarily true. I've gotten several books as "upgrades" when I bought the initial versions digitally. For example I got the Stryx Chronicles which was a setting/rule update which then got "upgraded" to the full Vampire the Requiem 2nd edition (bundling a lot more into it than just the updates).

Comment: This isn't about what to play, but about whether purchasing physical books is a good idea right now. It's also very much opinion-based.

Comment: I had the impression that DnD One specifically *is* somewhat like software in that it is a mild, backward-compatible upgrade to 5e (i.e., existing materials should mostly be compatible). Kind of like a drop-in replacement, to exhaust all possible IT terms. ;) I was looking specifically for whether there has been any official or unofficial statement from the makers in any of the material we have so far...

Comment: @AnoE Given what we've gotten so far, there are a LOT of questions of backward compatability being successful, but that's more of a discussion and you can join us in our very own [chat] if you'd like to engage in that :)